# How to javascript data to controller laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-table

I am new to laravel. I am trying to send javascript data to controller. 
In my view I have listed records using bootstrap table. When the user check the table row checkbox I want it's id to get store in the a variable and when the user click the add button it should send the id to the controller
html code

```
<div class="col-md-12" >

                             <table class="table table-hover"  data-toggle="table"  id="table"
                             data-click-to-select="true">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" ></th>

                                    <th data-field="roomname">Room Name</th>
                                    <th data-field="Desc">Description</th>
                                    <th data-field="price">Price</th>
                                    <th data-field="roomid" data-visible="false">Price</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody >
                                  @foreach($roomname as $value)
                                  <tr>

                                    <td>{!! $value->roomid !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $value->roomname !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $value->Desc !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $value->price !!}</td>
                                    <td >{!! $value->roomid !!}</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                              </table>



                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <br>

                      <button id="add_cart" class="btn btn-warning">Proceed to booking</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you try with ajax?

Comment: i used ajax but it throws error 505

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it without javascript if you make a route for it..

```
@foreach($roomname as $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $value->roomid !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->roomname !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->Desc !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->price !!}</td>
        <td >{!! $value->roomid !!}</td>
        <td><a href={!! route('routeName', ['id' => $value->roomid]) !!}
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

if you want to submit multiple id's to the controller for editing/booking that you can solve by a form or via ajax.

Comment: here is my ajax code not working
$("#add_cart").click(function() {
          $("#output").empty();
          $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) { data+= value.id + ',';
             $.ajax({
              url: 'booking/SelectedTableId',
              type: "post",
              data: {dataval:data},
              success: function(data){
                alert(data);
              }
            });
        });   
    });

Comment: plz nebody help me

Comment: @MassumHussain please dit your question to add ajax and your routes